# Alternative for Daemon Process

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jvm, daemon

When I open a project in the android studio (latest version), it gives the following error:

> ERROR: Unable to start the daemon process.
>
> This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>
> For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the
>   user guide chapter on the daemon at
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

Yes, I know that it is saying that there not enough Memory to run the Daemon Process as I have only **3GB RAM**. So what is the alternative for it?

Is there any issue if I'll not start the daemon process? As Only Android Studio consumes 800MB

Answer (score 0):

modify value of below mentioned variable in 'gradle.properties' in root of your project.

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

change it to 'org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx536m' and restart android studio.